# WAL Streaming Failure PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to setup streaming replication but I'm stuck, please help!

I followed the steps in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication

On Master I have
(postgresql.conf)

```
archive_mode = on
wal_level = archive
max_wal_senders = 5
wal_keep_senders = 150
```

(pg_hba.conf)

```
host replication user-with-rep IP/32 md5
```

On slave I have 
(recovery.conf)
primary_conninfo = ' host=IP port=5432 user=USER password=PWD '
standby_mode = 'on'
restore_command = 'copy "\\path\%f" "%p" '

I start services on primary and then do a backup with

```
psql -c "SELECT pg_start_backup('label', true)"
```

Then I copy all files from primary to standby with

```
xcopy from\path\* to\path /s /i /e
```

finally

```
psql -c "SELECT pg_stop_backup()"
```

When I execute pg_ctl start on my standby I get the following

```
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-05-27 14:16:41 EDT
LOG:  entering standby mode
LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000028" from archive
LOG:  redo starts at 0/28000090
LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/280000B8
LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 0/24000000 in log segment 000000010000000000000029, offset 0
LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/29000000 on timeline 1
```

And on my master I have

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-05-27 16:00:14 EDT
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

And then nothing else happens, please I really need help with this, I appreciate all comments. Any questions, please feel free to ask.

I would like to have this setup first and then do replication slots.

Comment: I'm setting up a warm standby by the way

Answer (score 1):

From your log, it looks like you were successful starting streaming replication.

> LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 0/24000000 in log segment 000000010000000000000029, offset 0
>
> LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/29000000 on timeline 1

To see more in your log, want to change the logging parameters:

```
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = '/var/log/postgresql/9.4'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'
log_truncate_on_rotation = on
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_rotation_size = 0
```

Adding `hot_standby = on` to your `postgresql.conf` also makes it easier for debugging as well.

Though, what you really should be doing to see if replication is working in your setup is something like this:

1. Create a table and generate traffic:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE t1 (a int, b int);

   INSERT INTO t1 (a,b)
       SELECT random()*100000, random()*100000
                FROM generate_series(1,1000000);
   ```
2. Check the status on the primary and secondary with these queries:

Primary:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_current_xlog_location();
```

Hot Standby:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_last_xlog_replay_location();
```

If the locations are exactly the same, or very close together, then everything is working just fine.

Hope that helps. =)

Comment: Name has changed from `xlog` to `wal`, and `location` to `lsn`. So the queries from pg version 10 to 15 will be: `SELECT * FROM pg_current_wal_lsn();` and 
`SELECT * FROM pg_last_wal_replay_lsn();` - source: [dbrnd: important name change](https://www.dbrnd.com/2017/12/postgresql-10-important-name-change-from-xlog-to-wal-and-location-to-lsn/)